# JUnit test - how to check Scanner for various input mismatches

Tags: java, testing, input, junit

I'm trying to write JUnit tests for a program that converts Fahrenheit degrees to Celsius degrees (and opposite). So my class looks like:

```
package asdf;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UnitTesting {

    public UnitTesting()
    {

    }

    public int returnInt()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        return x;
    }

    public double returnDouble()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = scanner.nextDouble();
        return x;
    }

    public double convertCtoF(double c) {
        return 1.8*c+32;
    }

    public double convertFtoC(double f) {
        return (5.0/9.0*(f-32));
    }

    public void menu()
    {
        int a;
        do {
            System.out.println("1 - convert C degrees to F degrees");
            System.out.println("2 - convert F degrees to C degrees");
            System.out.println("0 - exit");
            a = returnInt();
            switch(a)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println(convertCtoF(returnDouble()));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(convertFtoC(returnDouble()));
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Choose 1, 2 or 0");
                break;
            }
        }
        while(a!=0);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        UnitTesting ut = new UnitTesting();
        ut.menu();
    }
}
```

test class:

```
package asdf;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class UnitTestingTests {

    private UnitTesting ut;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
    ut = new UnitTesting();
    }

    @Test
    void checkIfInputMismatch() {
        ut.returnDouble();
        //some_kind_of_assert
    }

}
```

Since I wanted to test the user input's for various mismatch exceptions (NumberFormat, InputMismatch etc.) but I have no idea if this approach is possible for current methods `returnDouble()` and `returnInt()`. I was thinking of changing scanner to read input as a string (nextLine) but then extra parsing method would be needed. What would be needed to alter the methods/class to check if input is a number at all, or has a good format given by the user - in an "elegant" way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Some common techniques include:

- Separate user interaction and program logic (here temperature conversion) into separate classes. Unit test your logic alone. Very often one does not unit test the user interaction, but integration tests the entire program including user interaction (you may use JUnit or some other tool for this).
- Don’t create a new `Scanner` every time you read input. Use the same `Scaner` throughout. In this case it won’t be too hard to inject a different `Scanner` that reads from some other source than `System.in` for test purposes (if you really insisted on creating a new `Scanner` you might have method that in production creates a `Scanner` that reads from `System.in` and in test creates one that reads from some other source; but as I said, don’t bother).
- You may also set `System.in` to some other input stream than the keyboard for test purposes. And/or similarly rewire `System.out` to a different output stream that allows to test what is written to it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a library [System Rules](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules) that provide rules for populating `System.in` and reading output from `System.out`. Your Test may look like this:

```
package asdf;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class UnitTestingTests {
    @Rule
    public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock
        = emptyStandardInputStream();

    private UnitTesting ut;

    @Test
    void checkIfInputMismatch() {
        systemInMock.provideLines("1.23");

        double value = ut.returnDouble();

        //some_kind_of_assert
    }
}
```

Unfortunately System Rules does only support JUnit 4. I'm working on a test framework independent alternative for System Rules.

Answer (score 1):

To control the input is integer, double or an invalid input, you need to take input as string. Then you can use defined parse methods of wrapper classes.

```
package asdf;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UnitTesting {

    public int returnInt()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        try{
            int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
            return x;
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception, there you can give some messages to user.
            System.out.println("The input is invalid for integer.");
        }
    }

    public double returnDouble()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        try{
            double x = Integer.parseDouble(s);
            return x;
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception, there you can give some messages to user.
            System.out.println("The input is invalid for double.");
        }
    }

    public double convertCtoF(double c) {
        return 1.8*c+32;
    }

    public double convertFtoC(double f) {
        return (5.0/9.0*(f-32));
    }

    public void menu()
    {
        int a;
        do {
            System.out.println("1 - convert C degrees to F degrees");
            System.out.println("2 - convert F degrees to C degrees");
            System.out.println("0 - exit");
            a = returnInt();
            switch(a)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println(convertCtoF(returnDouble()));
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(convertFtoC(returnDouble()));
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Choose 1, 2 or 0");
                break;
            }
        }
        while(a!=0);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        UnitTesting ut = new UnitTesting();
        ut.menu();
    }
}
```

And the other way to control : Pattern matching

```
String input=...;
String pattern ="-?\\d+";
if(input.matches("-?\\d+")){ // any positive or negetive integer or not!
 ...
}
```